# How to arrange web page layout with bootstrap?

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the bootstrap framework for layout on my system. I want to arrange the layout of the page like this(**See image below**)
[image]

But I am facing a challenge. My code is showing this (**See image below**)
I need the Login forum section to go to the right like on the first picture that i have uploaded. 
[image]

**This is my code**

```html
<?php if($topics) : ?>
    <p id="topics">
        <div class="row">
        <?php foreach ($topics as $topic) : ?>
            <p class="topic">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
          </div> 

        <div class="col-md-5">
                <div class="topic-content pull-right">
                    <h3><a href="topic.php?id=<?php echo $topic['id']; ?>"><?php echo $topic['title']; ?></a></h3>
                    <div class="topic-info">
                        <a href="topics.php?category=<?php echo urlFormat($topic['category_id']); ?>"><?php echo $topic['name']; ?></a> >> 
                        <a href="topics.php?user=<?php echo urlFormat($topic['user_id']); ?>"><?php echo $topic['username']; ?></a> >>
                        Posted on: <?php echo formatDate($topic['create_date']); ?>
                    <span class="badge pull-right"><?php echo replyCount($topic['id']); ?></span>
                    </div>
                </div>    
            </div>
        </div>

            </p>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </p>
<?php else : ?>
    <p>No Topics to Display.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
<div class="col-md-4" align="pull-right">
                <div class="sidebar">
                    <div class="block">
                        <h3>Login Form</h3>
                        <?php if(isLoggedIn()) : ?>
                            <div class="userdata">
                                Logged in as <?php echo getUser()['username']; ?>
                            </div>
                            <br />
                            <form role="form" method="post" action="logout.php">
                                <input type="submit" name="do_logout" class="btn btn-default" value="Log Out" />
                                <hr>
                                 <h4><a href="/prac/forum">All Topics</a></h4>
                                <h4><a href="create.php">Create Topic</a></h4>

                            </form>
                        <?php else : ?>
                            <form role="form" method="post" action="login.php">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Username</label>
                                    <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Username" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Password</label>
                                    <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password" />
                                </div>
                                <button name="do_login" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button> <a class="btn btn-default" href="register.php">Create Account</a>
                            </form>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="block">
                        <h3>Categories</h3>
                        <div class="list-group">
                            <a href="topics.php" class="list-group-item <?php echo is_active(null); ?>">All topics <span class="badge pull-right"><?php echo totalPostCount() ;?></span></a>
                            <?php foreach(getCategories() as $category) : ?>
                                <a href="topics.php?category=<?php echo $category['id']; ?>" class="list-group-item <?php echo is_active($category['id']); ?>">
                                    <?php echo $category['name']; ?>
                                    <span class="badge pull-right">
                                        <?php echo postCountByCategory($category['id']) ;?>
                                    </span>
                            </a>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
    
</div>
<hr>

<h3>Forum Statistics</h3>

<p>
    <h6>Total Number of Users: <strong><?php echo $totalUsers; ?></strong></li>
    <h6>Total Number of Topics: <strong><?php echo $totalTopics; ?></strong></li>
    <h6>Total Number of Categories: <strong><?php echo $totalCategories; ?></strong></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `pull-right` is not a valid value for the `align` property.  Did you mean to add it to the class list?

Comment: Use the right balise like `<section></section>` or `<div><div/>` for the main element (not `<p></p>`, it's only for paragraph), no need to use `<br>` to go next line : an HTML element with `display:block;` will take all the lane as normal behavior. And read some bootstrap tuto to understand how a grid works :)

Comment: yes, please look at the pictures i have attached

Comment: @Rayobeats it looks like you are learning and try to reproduce the page bellow, what will you learn if you just copy/paste code? Try to do it using logic step by step : how many blocks can I see? (header? footer? side menu? how many section?..) How my element works on responsive? What is the css properties to get my element blue and underline? in bold? etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply use the bootstrap grid Grid system to achieve this task. Please checkout the official documentation through this link...
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

However, I created a sample layout that I think fit to your requirement.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../../../favicon.ico">

    <title>sample web page</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style type="text/css">
      .left-block{
        width:100%;
        height:500px;
        padding: 20px;

      }
      .right-block{
        width:100%;
        padding: 20px;
        height:500px;
        background-color: #D3D3D3;
      }
    </style>
    
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-8">
        <div class="left-block">
          <h1>sample content</h1>
          <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ullamcorper nisl ut sodales tincidunt. Praesent tristique lobortis tincidunt. Cras aliquet, lectus ut facilisis tempor, nulla felis porta sem, quis pulvinar lacus justo eget sapien. Integer dapibus bibendum sodales. Sed semper sagittis ex, et suscipit odio luctus vel. Fusce laoreet a sapien vitae mattis. Quisque ligula massa, sagittis vel odio vel, hendrerit iaculis leo. Aliquam erat volutpat. Fusce mollis, augue vel egestas tristique, nunc ligula placerat erat, sed venenatis elit ex et nulla. </p>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-4">
       <div class="right-block">
         <h2>Login Section</h2>
            <hr>
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
                     <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                   <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
                   <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
              </form>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
   
 </body>
</html>
```

still you have any problem, feel free to add a comment below...

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be plenty of unnecessary `rows` and `<p>` tags within other `<p>` tags. It needs a restructure to be honest. It is best practice not to wrap `divs` inside `<p>` tags as they shouldn't really be used as a wrapper.

You want to separate the 2 columns into 2 separate **Bootstrap cols** which should be wrapped inside a `row` class.

For example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
        <p>All your forum info here etc.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        *Login Form Here*
        *Categories Here*
    </div>
</div>
```

The columns above will separate them into 66.66666667% by 33.33333333% width columns on desktop and then both full width (100%) on smaller devices.

Answer (score 1):

Dont put structural divs inside a `<p>` tag! Try this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            This is one third of the page wide (4/12)
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            This is two thirds of the page wide (8/12)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="col-md-12">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
     <p> this is where 'normalization' text should go </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <p> this is where the form goes </p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Try above code. This is an example of basic bootstrap grid layout. The first  define the page as '12' - the remaining divs inside this must add up to 12 also, this example is 8 + 4 ( 2 columns ) but can also have 3 4+4+4 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following example to arrange the web page layout with Bootstrap:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-8">
 <p> Your Left area put here  </p>
 </div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <p> Your right area Put here </p>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div
```